# How can I keep the argument of TeXForm[Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + x], x]] from being evaluated?

Tags: evaluation, latex

How can I keep the argument of `TeXForm[Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + x], x]]` from being evaluated?

This is what I am getting:

```
TeXForm[Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + x], x]]
```

```latex
2 \sqrt{x+1}
```

But I want:

```latex
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} 1/\sqrt{x+1}
```

Comment: how about `TeXForm[HoldForm@Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + x], x]]`?

Comment: @kglr Works, thanks!

Comment: I suggest `TeXForm[Defer @ Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}]]` to get the exact output form you say you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) or [`Defer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) or [`Unevaluated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
TeXForm[HoldForm @ Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + x], x]]
```

> \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} \, dx

```
TeXForm[Defer @ Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + x], x]]
```

> > \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} \, dx

```
TeXForm[Unevaluated @ Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 + x], x]]
```

> \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} \, dx

> $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} \, dx$